# How to prevent crashing when Guzzle detect 400 or 500 error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I'm using PHP guzzle

I have tried

```
public static function get($url) {

    $client = new Client();

    try {
        $res = $client->request('GET',$url);
        $result = (string) $res->getBody();
        $result = json_decode($result, true);
        return $result;
    }
    catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    }

}
```

I kept getting

[image]

How to prevent crashing when Guzzle detecct 400 or 500 error ?

I just want my application to continue running and loading.

Comment: Try `catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e)` or put `use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;` up at the top of the file with other namespace instructions.

Comment: 10k'er and [I had to indent?](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46817723/2) *lol*

Comment: Where on the code ? sorry. I didn't mean to.

Comment: yeah but meh... no worries ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I'd bet your `get()` function exists in a namespace like `App\Http\Controllers`, which means this:

```
catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
```

is *actually* being interpreted as if you'd written:

```
catch (App\Http\Controllers\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
```

For obvious reasons, no exception of that kind is being thrown.

You can fix the namespacing issue by doing:

```
catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
```

(note the leading `\`) or putting:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
```

at the top of the file after the `namespace` declaration and catching just `ClientException`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php.

Comment: And, in the event the OP wants to return the body even if it's a 4xx or 5xx, the OP may use Guzzle's [`http_errors` setting](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#http-errors).

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at [`http_errors`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#http-errors) option to disable exceptions at all (if for your application it's an expected scenario, and you want to handle all responses specifically by yourself).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using just ClientException

You can try **RequestException**, which will help to handle bad requests.

```
try {
    // Your code here. 
} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
    if ($e->hasResponse()) {
        // Get response body
        // Modify message as proper response
        $message = $e->getResponse()->getBody();
        return (string) $exception;
     }
    else {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
public static function get($url) {


    try {
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET',$url);
        $result = (string) $res->getBody();
        $result = json_decode($result, true);
        return $result;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        if($e instanceof \GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException ){
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        }
      report($e);
      return false;
    }

}
```

The  `report()` helper function allows you to quickly report an exception using your exception handler's  report method without rendering an error page.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch any exception with this :

```
catch (\Exception $e)
```